# Xamarin and VS2017 component is missing

Tags: android, xamarin

I come to you because I have a problem with **Xamarin (Android)** and Visual Studio.
For Android project creation, I have no worries and also when I launch my application with **ADB**.
However, I miss in my project an important part which is "component". I would like to be able to use the store of Xamarin but for the moment it is impossible. Here is a picture to illustrate my problem.

[image]

I thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Components [have been deprecated](https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/) in favor of Nuget Packages

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

So, to install a component of the store Xamarin, you have to go through Nuget and install the component by command line or there is another solution?